# How to iterate over an integer range when you don't know if it is in increasing or decreasing order?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a range in one loop and NOT using below two for-loops:

```
if (firstIndex <= secondIndex)
    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= secondIndex; i++)
    {...}
else
    for (int i = firstIndex; i >= secondIndex; i--)
    {...}
```

I considered using boost::irange but it does not cover *secondIndex* index.

Update: I need to preserve the order and CANNOT swap indices.

Comment: Personally I'd rework to a function `foo(x, y)` and in the first line of that function check `if (x > y) foo(y, x)`. Interesting problem though, +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba I need to maintain the order too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a contrived way, you can use

```
for (int i= first; 
  first >= second ? (i <= second) : (i >= second); 
  i+= first >= last ? +1 : -1)
```

---

A variant is possible with a increment variable and multiplies. I don' like it much.

```
int inc= first >= second ? +1 : -1;
for (int i= first; inc * i <= inc * second; i+= inc)
```

Comment: I need to preserve the order. I cannot swap indices. :(

Comment: I mean I need to start iteration with firstIndex. [i= first >= second ? first : second;] @Yves

Comment: @bathsheba: nobody's perfect: I was wrong anyway :)

Comment: @9121: oops, sorry, you are right, Fixing. The solution is in fact simpler.

Comment: It is a good approach. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Find out what is similar, and what is different; copy the former, abstract out the latter.

First we find out the direction, as the sign of the difference of indices. Per comments, it is better to not use the sign `0` and still use the incrementing solution when `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` are same.

Now `i <= secondIndex` and `i >= secondIndex` can both be abstracted as `i * sign <= secondIndex * sign`, and `i++` and `i--` as `i += sign`.

```
int sign = (secondIndex > firstIndex) ? 1 : -1;
for (int i = firstIndex; i * sign <= secondIndex * sign; i += sign) { ... }
```

Comment: I like the expression diff>0 - diff<0. Anyway diff >=0 ? +1 : -1 is slightly safer as it voids endless looping when diff==0.

Comment: This said, your solution is wrong when sign<0.

Comment: `int sign = (diff > 0) - (diff < 0);`. U wot?

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right on all points, I forgot to multiply the other side. Fixed, I hope.